# Variable in Javascript for uploadify form data is undefined

Tags: javascript, uploadify

Hi I need to save a variable in Javascript and give it to uploadify.

This is my code:

```
var mediaID;

$(".edit_photo_media").live("click", function() {
    mediaID = $(this).data("media-id");
    $.ajax({
        url: 'edit.php?action=media_select',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (select) {
            if (select == '3') {
                document.location = "login.php";
            } else {
                $("#dialog_upload_media").dialog("open");
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});

$('#file_upload').uploadify({
    'fileTypeDesc' : 'Image Files',
    'fileTypeExts' : '*.jpg;',
    'fileSizeLimit' : '4096KB',
    'debug'    : true,
    'method'   : 'post',
    'formData'      : {'id' : '' + mediaID},
    'swf'      : 'include/swf/uploadify.swf',
    'uploader' : 'include/scripts/upload_mult.php'
});
```

So everytime before the uploader is opened .edit_photo_media is clicked.

```
<a href="#" data-media-id="'.$getID[$i].'" data-table="Media" class="edit_photo_media" title="Foto hochladen"><img src="images/photo.png" /></a>
```

This is where the var mediaID is getting its content. Inside .edit_photo_media mediaID is defined correct.

But if I click the upload button mediaID is undefined. Why is the variable loosing its value?

Edit: Ok this seems to be related to a uploadify bug? If I check mediaID on any other function it is working fine... rlly strange

Comment: You could try $(this).attr("data-media-id"); instead of $(this).data()

Comment: Im getting same undefined result with `$(this).attr("data-media-id");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok problem solved. Just added 'onUploadStart' and saved the id in there

```
$('#file_upload').uploadify({
    'fileTypeDesc' : 'Image Files',
    'fileTypeExts' : '*.jpg;',
    'fileSizeLimit' : '4096KB',
    'buttonText'    : 'Bilder auswählen',
    'debug'    : true,
    'method'   : 'post',
    'formData' : {'id' : 0},
    'swf'      : 'include/swf/uploadify.swf',
    'uploader' : 'include/scripts/upload_mult.php',
    'onUploadStart' : function(file) {
        $('#file_upload').uploadify("settings", "formData", {"id": mediaID});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery only started subsuming HTML5 data properties set in the source code from version 1.6 onwards. If you're using < 1.6, this won't happen, in which case upgrade jQ.